# Oracle Connection request timed out

Tags: c#, oracle, connection-pooling

I am getting the following error sometimes when there is new OracleConnection using Oracle Managed Driver libraries in .net

I want to know what type of this exception is , i need to handle it in catch block.

```
    Message:Connection request timed out Stack Trace: at
 OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.CreateNewPR(Int32 reqCount, Boolean bForPoolPopulation, ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, String instanceName) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean
 bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString
 csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword,
 SecureString securedProxyPassword) at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() at ClientService.ClientService.AuthenticateUser(String subno, String pin,
 String version
```

Comment: Can you catch `OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`?

Comment: Nope it does not highlight.

Comment: How about `OracleException`?

Comment: yes i can catch OracleException but problem is i need to know this particular type of exception like in the post i said its related to ConnectionPool

Answer (score 1):

Your problem related with using of pooling as default attribute in connection string. This issue discussed in detail in this document: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732.pdf in "Using connection pooling" chapter.